# Pagination In TableView, like in iPhone's youtube application

Tags: iphone

I like to implement pagination in tableview.

I am getting few information from internet as XML(thumbnail url).

I like to implement it with out using [self.tableview reloaddata].
This API will load all cell again. But i want to insert only the new data in cell(no need to trouble old data) just like in the youtube application in iPhone.

How could i implement pagination without using reloaddata.

Please, any one can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer, i have to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Thank you